# Deleting Lamp and guest account without affecting default or main Root account

Tags: 14.04, 13.04, server, apache2, root

I'm new to adding accounts and I notice that the programs installed in the regular default/main root account are also installed in the newuser (guest) account I created with root privileges as well. I would like to install lamp (which I know how to do) in the additional root user account and log into it and install lamp but I don't want lamp to be in the regular main/default root account because of the localhost access.

My question is In the default main root account is Lamp accessible from here and when the newuser account is no longer needed and you delete it through the regular default/main root account does lamp get entirely uninstall? 
or
Is there a specific way to install lamp so it can stay in the new user account and later delete it. Any insight will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem like you may be confused about how Ubuntu installs software.

Software installed by Ubuntu (eg, by any of its package managers) will be installed system-wide, for all users.  Ubuntu doesn't have an official concept of installing software for just one user.

Most software that needs to store user preferences (particularly desktop GUI software) will store its configuration separately for each user, in that user's home directory.  Non-privileged users cannot modify/break software for other users.

If you do want to provide separate environments for different users, with different sets of system software installed, you *can* achieve this using chroot, or even using a more complete virtualisation solution.  But in all likelihood this isn't what you actually need, you just need to provide certain users with the ability to modify the web server files.

In which case, you do this with file permissions.  Add the users who you need to be able to modify the web server files to a group with `adduser user group`, then modify the permissions on the web server files (such as /var/www) to allow group editing and to specify the group.  How to achieve this is probably the scope of another question.

Comment: Yes I was confuse. Was thinking in windows world. But with your explanation now it makes sense. Thank you.